# Nativescript angular : handle android back button on different pages

Tags: nativescript

So I use this function to handle android back button :

```
this._page.on(Page.loadedEvent, event => {
        if (application.android) {
            application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (args:AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {      
                args.cancel = true;
                this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['/parameters']);
                });
            });
        }
    })
```

on different pages (angular components). So on page1.ts I have navigate(['/parameters]) and on page2.ts I have console.log("test"). Problem is wherever I am in the app, pressing back button always do navigate(['/parameters]), also the console.log if i'm on the right page, but it should do console.log **only**.
It seems to be global, any idea how to override activityBackPressedEvent ?

Comment: are the pages siblings or parent/child?

Comment: no they're linked to different modules

Comment: so siblings then? unless something is misbehaving, i dont see how one page would be able to detect the back press on another, ive only known parent/child pages to do that before

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`activityBackPressedEvent` is not specific to a page, it's global to your Activity which holds all the pages. Generally, You will not add more than one event listener to this event.

You could do something like below to handle this on page level, probably in app module / `main.ts`

```
application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent,
    (args: application.AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
        const page = frame.topmost().currentPage;
        if (page.hasListeners(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent)) {
            args.cancel = true;
            page.notify({
                eventName: application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent,
                object: page
            });
        }
    });
```

With above code, `activityBackPressedEvent` willl be triggered on every page that has a listener.

Now in your page / component in which you want to customise the behaviour you do this,

```
// Inject Page
constructor(private page: Page) { 
   this.page.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.onBackButtonTap, this);
}

onBackButtonTap(data: EventData) {
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['/parameters']);
            });
}
```

Comment: It is probably a good solution. I can't successfully test due to unrelated errors popping up when trying. But I will try to fix it or test a similar workaround and report back. Thank you !

Comment: @Manoj where can i import application?

Comment: From `import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application"`

Comment: how about the frame?

Comment: `import * as frame from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame"`

Comment: @Manoj : I have implemented the same thing you mentioned, it seems to be working but when I click on back button 'onBackButtonTap' function is called twice.

Comment: It would if you have two active listeners, double check and if issue persists, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: @Manoj : okay I will check that, one question : If I have parent component which has multiple child component then if I set the back listener only in parent component will work  or do I need to set listener for each child component too?

Comment: Back listener is on activity, doesn't matter how many frames / child components you have.

Comment: @Manoj - Quick question: I have a parent component which has one modal window. Scenarios:  I'm on modal window, If I hit back button, parent component listener is getting triggered. How do we restrict parent component trigger when I was on modal window?

Comment: `activityBackPressedEvent` must be triggered for modal dialogs too, but if you don't have a frame & page in your modal then you should probably handle it within the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you added the handle back button in the event `pageLoaded` that's why it does not work on other page.

The code that handle back button should be placed in the app starter. I'm using NS Vue & I place this code in my `main.js`. I think it could be similar in NS angular.

```
application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (args:AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {      
            args.cancel = true;
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/parameters']);
            });
});
```