# Overriding the Android Back Button in NativeScript for only one page

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm using NativeScript version 5.2.4 with TypeScript, I am trying to handle back button to disable it, and I need to disable it only in one page, but it make the back button for a child page doing the same behavior (I mean make it disable), this is my code..

```js
 constructor(page: Page, obj: any = null, initValues = true) {
        super(page, obj, initValues);
  this.title = Helpers.getString('visit_cart');
        if (obj != null) {
            this.Parse(obj);
        }
        else {
            this.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
            application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (args: any) => {
                args.cancel = true;
                Helpers.infoMsg('press_end_visit');
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: your code looks right? is that code within the page you want to disable the back button on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nativescript angular : handle android back button on different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297104/nativescript-angular-handle-android-back-button-on-different-pages)

Comment: I hope you are using Angular as you are trying to inject Page in constructor. But I'm not sure as you are injecting  variables like obj, initValues. Still the given solution should work irrespective of your flavour for development.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes this code inside the page that i want to disable the back button and its work well but my problem is when i navigate to another page from this page, the back button for the new page is disabled too.

Comment: @Manoj Unfortunately, I don't use Angular in this code.

Comment: unless the page you navigate is a child of that page, that code wont be active as it should destroy the page

Comment: @Abdullatif Thanks for confirming and as I mentioned already the same solution works irrespective of the flavour you use for development.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

You can use Location from `@angular/common`.

```
constructor(_location: Locationpage: Page, obj: any = null, initValues = true) {
        super(page, obj, initValues);
        const path = this._location.path()
        this.title = Helpers.getString('visit_cart');
        if (obj != null) {
            this.Parse(obj);
        }
        else {
            this.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
            application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (args: any) => {
if(path === 'You Page'){
                args.cancel = true;
}
                Helpers.infoMsg('press_end_visit');
            });
        }

    }
```